# Importing data into specific fields from CSV - into pre-existing nodes?

Tags: entities, importing-exporting

I've used the Feeds module before to import nodes and users. I need to import data into new fields on pre-existing nodes - is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Feeds requires you to map a unique identifier in order to update existing content; I've not tried this but presumably if your existing content has a unique field/property which you can map to your import then you will be able to update existing content.

Comment: I'll experiment & see. It's possible I may not need to do this after all (you know how clients can be ;)).